# Segmentation Fault while Reading from File

Tags: c++, file, segmentation-fault

I am trying to print last 10 lines of a file. Following is my code, but it is giving a segmentation fault due to fscanf. While running with gdb the fault reads : vfscanf.c: No such file or directory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("microfile.txt","r");
    char *c[10];
    int idx = 0;
    cout<<fp<<"\n";
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        if(idx<10)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%s",c[idx]);
            idx++;
        }
        else if(idx==10)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<idx-1;i++)
            {
                c[i] = c[i+1];
            }
            fscanf(fp,"%s",c[idx-1]);
        }
    }
    int i=0;
    while(i<10)
    {
        cout<<c[i]<<"\n";
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: why aren't you using c++?

Comment: Are you aware that your code is almost C. The only C++ stuff is the cout. You should learn how to do the equivalent in C++ or switch to C.

Comment: `c[idx]`, I don't see where is `c[ids]` allocated.

Comment: Do you *know* what dynamic memory allocation is? Do you know what in indeterminate pointer is? Finally do you know you're not doing the former, and are using an array of 10 of the later, each as the target of a `fscanf` and thereby invoking **undefined behavior** ?

Comment: @0x499602D2 and he *is* using C++, or I'm fairly sure that `#include <iostream>` would puke all over the place. If your questioning why the OP isn't using the C++-only *standard library* features, I completely agree.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem comes from the fact you have an array of *pointers* on this line:

```
char* c[10];
```

And later on in the program you attempt to assign character values to these pointers. Maybe you meant for just an array of characters instead:

```
char c[10];
```

Moreover, use of the Standard library is recommended. Try using `std::string` and standard streams and your program can be made more maintainable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s;

    s.assign(
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::ifsteam("microfile.txt").rdbuf()),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    for (char c : s)
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```